Проблема с парсингом инфы с сайта csr
Пытаюсь вывести информацию с сайта, которая приходит в ответах, но приходит ошибка.
from email.quoprimime import header_check
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import fake_useragent

header = {
    "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:133.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/133.0",
    "Accept-Language": "ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br, zstd",
    "Content-Type": "text/plain",
    "Origin": "https://www.launchmynft.io",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Referer": "https://www.launchmynft.io/",
    "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
    "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
    "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-site",
    "TE": "trailers"
}
# --compressed -X POST -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:133.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/133.0" -H "Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*" -H "Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br, zstd" -H "Content-Type: text/plain" -H "Origin: https://www.launchmynft.io" -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "Referer: https://www.launchmynft.io/" -H "Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty" -H "Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors" -H "Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site" -H "TE: trailers" --data-raw
# "{""searches"":^[{""query_by"":""collectionName,owner"",""per_page"":10,""sort_by"":""lastMintedAt:desc"",""highlight_full_fields"":""collectionName,owner"",""collection"":""collections"",""q"":""*"",""facet_by"":""soldOut,twitterVerified,type,cost"",""filter_by"":""soldOut:=^[false^] && twitterVerified:=^[true^]"",""max_facet_values"":10,""page"":1},{""query_by"":""collectionName,owner"",""per_page"":10,""sort_by"":""lastMintedAt:desc"",""highlight_full_fields"":""collectionName,owner"",""collection"":""collections"",""q"":""*"",""facet_by"":""soldOut"",""filter_by"":""twitterVerified:=^[true^]"",""max_facet_values"":10,""page"":1},{""query_by"":""collectionName,owner"",""per_page"":10,""sort_by"":""lastMintedAt:desc"",""highlight_full_fields"":""collectionName,owner"",""collection"":""collections"",""q"":""*"",""facet_by"":""twitterVerified"",""filter_by"":""soldOut:=^[false^]"",""max_facet_values"":10,""page"":1}^]}
#pip install os subprocess

def parse_cost():
    response = requests.get('https://s.launchmynft.io/multi_search?x-typesense-api-key=UkN4Vnd3V2JMWWVIRlFNcTJ3dng4VGVtMGtvVGxBcmJJTTFFYS9MNXp1WT1Ha3dueyJmaWx0ZXJfYnkiOiJoaWRkZW46ZmFsc2UiLCJleGNsdWRlX2ZpZWxkcyI6ImhpZGRlbiIsInF1ZXJ5X2J5IjoiY29sbGVjdGlvbk5hbWUsb3duZXIiLCJsaW1pdF9oaXRzIjoyMDAsInNuaXBwZXRfdGhyZXNob2xkIjo1MH0%3D', headers=header)
    data = response.json()
    return data

print(parse_cost())


Это правда { "message": "Not Found"}
